# how to get number of rows in a SQLite3 query in Swift

Tags: sql, swift, sqlite

The cmd `sqlite3_column_count(statement)` works well in my SQLite3 query in Swift.

However, I would like to get the number of rows (not columns) of my query. What is the appropriate cmd for that ? (i.e.`sqlite3_row_count` does not seem to exist).

Any idea appreciated !

Here is my code :

```
    // Open SQLite database
    var db: OpaquePointer? = nil
    if sqlite3_open(self.fileURL, &db) == SQLITE_OK {

        // Run SELECT query from db
        var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {

            // Loop through all results from query
            var stop_id_memory = ""

            // !!!!!!!! works well !!!!!!!!!!!!!
            print(sqlite3_column_count(statement))

            // !!!!!!!! does not work well !!!!!!!!!!!!!
            print(sqlite3_row_count(statement))

            while sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW {
               let id = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)
               // do whatever with the id ....
               // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution with the counter inside the while...

```
var query1: String = ".....my first query....."
var query2: String = ".....my second query...."
var i = 0
var usedQuery = ""

// Open SQLite database
var db: OpaquePointer? = nil
if sqlite3_open(self.fileURL, &db) == SQLITE_OK {

    // Run SELECT query from db
    var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query1, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {

        // Loop through all results from query
        while sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW {
            i = i + 1
        }
    }
    if (i < 5 ) {
        usedQuery = query2
    } else {
        usedQuery = query1
    }
    statement = nil
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, usedQuery, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {

        // Loop through all results from query
        var stop_id_memory = ""
        while sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW {
            let id = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)
            // do whatever with the id ....
            // ...
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you preparing and running the query twice? Just do it once. Add your counter the loop you have that gets the actual data.

Comment: If it works for you, then that's fine with me.  But that's not a very efficient approach.  And that's not exactly how you do it with SQLite.

Comment: Depending on the number of elements in the query1 I need to do another query (i..e query2). What I agree is bad that in certain cases query1 gets repeated (i.e. when i>=5 in the example). How could I do it differently if this supposedly is not the way to do it ??